# Zabbix flapping detection

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, alerts

TL/DR: Is there flapping detection available in Zabbix ?

expanded question: 
I'm trying to achieve same behaviour in Zabbix alerts as I've seen in Nagios: When monitored service is in unstable state and triggers several Up/Down events for some period of time "flapping detection" generates one alert for *flapping* and silent all other Up/Down alerts until service is stable.

What did I do already: I tried to increase timespan and/or amount of events to trigger alarm state. This approach makes it less sensible and still doesn't solve flapping problem.

May be I just don't understand something in Zabbix trigger logic ?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be to use hysteresis in trigger expressions, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/triggers/expression#hysteresis .

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at it yesterday. Thanks, will update my question if I succeed

Answer (score 0):

See this video for demonstration of Hysteresis.
https://youtu.be/alga7oQpSqM
[image: Zabbix Alert Flapping]

With Hysteresis you set a different condition for the Resolve event.

The video also shows using 'manual close' for the trigger,
and also changing the alert severity dependant on you media type settings.